# Docker nginx redirect HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker

I'm setting up a server using Docker. One container runs an nginx image with SSL configured. A second container runs with a simple node app (on port 3001). I've got the two containers communicating with a --link docker parameter.

I need to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS. Looking at other threads and online sources, I found `return 301 https://$host$request_uri`. When I type http://localhost in the browser I'm getting the upstream's name in the browser (https://node_app instead of https://localhost). How can I successfully redirect without defining a server_name or explicitly defining a domain?

**Edit**: I should clarify that accessing https://localhost directly  in the browser works. HTTP does not.

Here's my nginx.conf file:

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

  upstream node_app {
    server node:3001;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://node_app/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: just the same way as you do for bare-metal linux box running nginx. Just google it for a minute or less. Exposing both listen ports within docker doesn't seem to be your problem at the moment (HTTPS to be exposed same way as HTTP, just in case)

Comment: The `nginx` configuration looks fine. Could the node app be changing the domain name? Use a browser plug-in or curl to analyse the `Location` header in the HTTP response to identify the exact sequence of redirects.

Comment: @RichardSmith Ran `curl http://localhost --head` and got the following response. Looks like the location is correct.

`HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.11.5
Date: Sun, 16 Oct 2016 13:58:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 185
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://localhost/`

Comment: What happens if you change `proxy_pass` to `proxy_pass http://node_app;`?

Comment: This is very weird! I'm only seeing this behavior in Google Chrome. Safari and Firefox are able to successfully redirect `http://localhost` to `https://localhost`. Any ideas?

Comment: Tried in Chrome's incognito and it worked. Looks like I need to clean up browser cache, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like everything was okay. Tried some curl calls to make sure headers were being set correctly (credits to @RichardSmith for recommendation). Also tested in different browsers. Everything worked! Turns out I needed to clear my primary browser's cache. Not sure why, but it resolved the issue!

For anyone interested in controlling the cache of 301 redirects done by nginx: https://serverfault.com/questions/394040/cache-control-for-permanent-301-redirects-nginx